# What are the onomatopoeia for opening and closing of a door (respectively)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> From behind, I heard the _ and _ of a door.

What are those two words?

Comment: One could certainly be *creak*.

Comment: Not everything has an onomatopoeia - perhaps *woosh*? But that could be a door opening or closing.

Comment: Opening a drawer doesn't have a distinctive sound, hence no distinctive word for it exists. Closing, however, falls within the phonosemantic range of the `KL-` assonance in English, which have to do with things being or moving together, frequently with considerable force applied, and often making a distinctive noise. See [the Venn diagram](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the *pull* and [*thud*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thud) of a door.

While *pull* isn't ordinarily considered onomatopoeia, its pronunciation is suggestive of the sound of air rushing through as a tightly-sealed door is opened.

Comment: Or *slide* and *seal* if the door is of the sliding variety.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how the door was opened/closed. Potential words include

- slammed
- clicked
- banged
- creaked

Comment: Yes. It also depends on the door—I have one that creaks no matter how careful I am; a very large and heavy door might thud; a really good, well-maintained door should be virtually silent; etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the sound of the door can be left up to the imagination of the reader? The writer has already deduced that the sounds are from a door, so the whole statement could be simply:

From behind, I heard the **opening** and **closing** of a door.

Or

From behind, I heard the **unlocking** and **opening** of a door.

Or

From behind, I heard the **closing** and **locking** of a door.

Otherwise, any sound associated with a door fits. For example:

From behind, I heard the **creaking** and **slamming** of a door.

Comment: +1 for *opening* and *closing* which are as generic as the door the question asks about!